What's this "media not available" error message from?
Ok, so I was watching a The Matrix (1999) Behind the Scenes video, and around 56:29 I noticed a flash across the screen of some ancient error message. What software was this from:?
ChatGPT confidently speculates that it's from RealPlayer, but I doubt it.

Anyone know?

Great question. I can't find an answer - I assumed it was an old verison of Avid. You could try https://www.reddit.com/r/ObscureMedia/
